# Is there any way at all to bypass sector-level CRC when reading damaged CDs?

Tags: data-recovery, compact-disc

I'm trying to image damaged CDs, some of which have bad sectors in important areas. I know there are tons of software out there that will create a disk image even if they run into bad sectors. My problem is that those bad sectors are just skipped (copied as zeros). Is there any way at all to instruct or force the drive to return what it managed to read in a damaged sector, regardless of whether the sector's CRC was OK - pretty much force it to behave as if it is reading an audio CD? I did not find any information on this, so I'll be very thankful if anyone has any information on this. I'm not afraid to write some assembly code or do some soldering either, so any tips are welcome.

Here are some things I've already tried:

- Use different imaging/copying software, including ddrescue, imgburn, and winhex. CD is read as a data disk and bad sectors are not returned by the drive.
- Read CD in raw access mode.

Some ideas (please post if you know that any of these will/will not work):

- Issue some low-level ATA command to disable CRC / force drive into audio CD mode?
- Custom firmware?
- Insert audio CD then swap to the needed data CD without opening tray?

Any other ideas are welcome, no matter how crazy :)

Comment: Short answer: I'm sure it is possible. I thought that happened when you took a bin/cue image or read in "raw" mode, but even if it doesn't, I'm still sure it's possible, but have no clue how.

Comment: I have tried using raw mode - in good sectors, I get back everything - the frame counters, the sector data itself, and the error correction related data. But in bad sectors - nothing, just an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I should go back and answer this myself, now that I'm experienced in this subject. Two of the ideas I thought of in my original question do, in fact, work!

> Issue some low-level ATA command to disable CRC / force drive into audio CD mode?

This is indeed possible on some drives (1 of the 2 drives I tested support this). You need the ability to send generic packets to the drive. This can be done in (probably) any linux distro by using the CDROM_SEND_PACKET ioctl call. First you need to issue a MODE_SENSE_10 command to the drive with page code 1 (read-write error recovery). Using the page control value 0 (current values), you will be able to see the drive's behaviors for bad sectors, and with the page control value 1 (changeable values) see which ones can be changed. If your drive supports changing the TB (transfer block) setting of that page, you should set TB to 1 and send the modified settings to the drive using the MODE_SELECT_10 command. Et voila - you now get the sector back from the drive even if there were EDC/ECC/CIRC errors! The best part is that the drive DOES perform sector descrambling and whatever error correction it can, before sending you the sector. (Untested: there's also a DCR setting which probably disables error correction attempts entirely.)

If you find this interesting, grab a linux livecd and a Mt. Fuji specification! The info above can be found on page 752 of Mt. Fuji spec v.9 revision 1.00.

Bonus: now that you can send generic packets to your drive, you should be using the READ CD (0xBE) command to get the raw sectors yourself. You can then examine all headers, EDC/ECC data, and even subchannel data yourself, if you're into that sort of thing. When the drive gives you a corrupt sector, you can use the EDC/ECC data to examine just how corrupt your sector is and, when you re-read it, decide which of the two attempts to keep.

> Insert audio CD then swap to the needed data CD without opening tray?

Believe it or not this actually works! (at least on some very old cdrom drive I used to test). You can literally get an audio CD player to 'play' your data, record it, and after correcting any sector drift (by looking for the data sectors' sync headers) and descrambling the data (look into ECMA 130 scrambling lookup table), you get your raw data, without any kind of error correction. I'm pretty sure my 1st method above obsoletes this method, but time will tell - I'm still only getting started with actual data recovery.

I'm currently developing some software for automating the stuff I just wrote, and for perfectly (meaning incl. any control headers and subchannel data) archiving old, corrupt CDs. If anyone's interested in this work, please let me know. Also, please let me know, if this kind of software already exists - AFAIK it does not.

Comment: What was the drive model that this worked?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the current spec, but an older ATA document mentions no capability of obtaining unreadable sectors.

Note that your experience of not able to unconditionally retrieve disk data refutes a widespread misconception that disk data is transferred directly from the read head to the drive interface and on to the host PC.  If this misconception were actually true, then the PC memory buffer would have the "raw" data before any error detection and correction could be applied.

This misconception is often used to "prove" that the "slow" bit rate of the read head will slowdown the data bit rate on the SATA bus, and then erroneous conclude that fast SATA transfer rates have little benefit (unless the sector data comes from the drive cache).

However the sector data is always read from the head into a sector buffer.
Once the entire sector is read in, then the sector data is validated.
Only if the sector data is deemed "good" (or correctable) will transfer to the PC host commence.
Detection of an uncorrectable read error will trigger a retry if the command allows it.
Otherwise the host PC will receive a command abort status.

Note that an "unreadable sector" also includes the situation of the controller unable to "find" the sector (actually its ID record).

Comment: Thanks for the info! This at least proves that there's no standard ATA command that can disable hardware CRC. However, I have come across drives that read audio CDs without performing hardware CRC. What I want to try later is to initialize a drive with an audio CD, then swap it with the data CD I want to recover, without ejecting the tray. Might this work or would I be wasting my time? I'm afraid that swapping the media type like this will simply cause subsequent seeking to fail.

Comment: ATAPI (e.g. SATA packets) uses CRC. Disk sectors use **ECC**, Error Correction Code. HDDs used to use a 11-byte ECC based on Hamming code. CD-ROMs use a 276-byte ECC based on Reed-Solomom code. Look at line 294+ in [CD-ROM sector information](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.5/include/linux/cdrom.h).  I don't know if you can 
fool the read logic/processing of the drive/controller.  The format or mode of the CD-ROM is encoded in the sector header. You would have to ensure that the drive always ignores that specifier after the sector is read in to avoid/skip error detection/processing.

Comment: Just a quick update - a while ago, I actually got a CD drive to read a data CD as audio by doing the disk swap trick. I'll look into reversing the data encoding when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

`ddrescue` is a data recovery tool. It copies data from one file or block device (hard disc, cdrom, etc) to another, trying hard to rescue data in case of read errors.

AFAIK it is for Linux only

Comment: I tried using ddrescue some time ago, and pretty much had the same result. The CD was read normally as a data disk and any bad sectors were not returned at all by the drive. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score -1):

If the damages are scratches it's easier to mitigate these scratches by waxing (no polish) the CD's. If have good experiences doing that. With CD(RW)s, reflecting not enough light, you should try several different drives. Some of the drives and brands are much more sensitive then others. This also applies for scratches.